# Probability of events with retries?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say I want to roll $n$ 20-sided dice, and I want none of those dice to be a 1. I figure that the probability at least one die will be a 1 is $\frac{19}{20}^n$. But now let's say that we will re-roll each individual die that is a 1 up to $r$ times. I want to know 2 things:

1. Given the above, what is the probability one or more of the dice will be a 1?
2. Suppose I play this game a million times. How many dice rolls will a given game make on average? In other words, for each game, I will make $n+t$ dice rolls, where $t$ is the number of retries I've made. What would $t$ be on average?

Comment: The probability for exactly one die to be 1 is $${n \choose 1}\left(\frac{1}{20}\right)\left(\frac{19}{20}\right)^{n-1}$$

Comment: I suppose I should refine the question: what is the probability one or more dice is 1?

Comment: Can you clarify what "How many dice rolls will a given game make on average?" means? I don't follow what you're asking for there.

Comment: Dear Jason, please clarify the question by editing it. Am leaving this question open only because I remember probability comes as an important topic in many technical interviews.

Comment: @Nick - Better?

Comment: @JasonBaker thank you, Jason. Good question :)

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question right,

1. Let's consider one game, the probability of getting a $1$ is given by $1-\left( \frac{19}{20} \right)^r$, now the probability of getting at least a $1$ is the complement of getting no $1$s, that is $1-\left(1-1+ \left( \frac{19}{20} \right)^r \right)^n=1-\left( \frac{19}{20} \right)^{nr}$
2. I will ignore the million time thing, since if you take the average of an expectation you end up with the same result (due to unbiasedness of the average estimator). For one game, the probability of throwing the die $k\in [1:r-1]$ times is $\frac{1}{20} \left( \frac{19}{20} \right)^{k-1}$ and the probability of throwing $r$ times is $\left( \frac{19}{20} \right)^{r-1}$ (the last throw can be $1$ or not). A good sanity check is to verify this sums to $1$.
   To obtain the expectation we compute 
   \begin{align*}
   &\frac{1}{20} \sum_{k=1}^{r-1} k \left( \frac{19}{20} \right)^{k-1} + r \left( \frac{19}{20} \right)^{r-1}\\
   =&\left(\frac{19}{20}\right)^{r - 1} r + \frac{20}{19} \frac{(-19 (19^r - 20^r) - 19^r r)}{20^{r}}
   \end{align*}
   by the [Arithmetico-geometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence) (and after few steps)

EDIT : I think that my first one is wrong, see Mike Earnest's answer. And by the way you may have to use $r+1$ instead of $r$ in my formula for the second one depending if you are allowed throw the dice $r$ times or re-throw it $r$ times

Comment: If I understand the second part correctly, it seems that it only calculates the number of retried rolls. So then if I want the total number of rolls, I would have to add n?

Comment: Well you would need to do $n$ times the experiment so multiply the result by $n$. But if you are looking for the average then you also need to divide by $n$ which cancels and so the result is what I gave.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a die to end up being $1$, it has come up $1$ a total of $r+1$ times in a row. Therefore, each die ends up being one with probability $(1/20)^{r+1}$, so 
$$
P(\text{at least one die is }1)=1-P(\text{no dice are }1)=\boxed{1-\bigg(1-\frac1{20^{r+1}}\bigg)^n.}
$$
To compute the expected number of rolls, we compute the expected number of rolls for each die and multiply by $n$. Let $X$ be the number times a particular die is rolled, and let's compute $P(X> k)$. The die is rolled more than $k$ times if and only if its first $k$ rolls are $1$, and $k<r$. Therefore,
$$
P(X>k) = \frac{1}{20^k},\qquad k=0,1,\dots,r.
$$
Then the expected value is
$$
E[X]=\sum_{k=0}^r P(X>k)=\sum_{k=0}^r  \frac{1}{20^k}=\frac{1-(1/20)^{r+1}}{1-1/20}.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
E[\#\text{ of rolls}]=n\cdot E[X]=\boxed{n\cdot \frac{20}{19}\Big(1-\frac{1}{20^{r+1}}\Big).}
$$
For example, when $r=0$, the expected number of rolls is $n$. As $r$ tends to infinity, the expected number of rolls tends to $n\cdot \frac{20}{19}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the output of the last formula. If I assume 0 retries, then it always gives me 1. Should I multiply the number by $n$ to get the total number of rolls?

Comment: @JasonBaker Oh, when you said rolls, I though you meant you rerolled all the die at once, so the number of rolls was always at most $r+1$. Like in Yahtzee how the number of rolls is always at most 3, instead of 15. I’ll fix

Comment: Oh, no we'd re-roll the dice individually

Comment: @JasonBaker Fixed. But why are you counting the number of individual die rolls?

Comment: I'm trying to run a program that has a certain chance of success over a large set of inputs. I'm trying to determine how adding retries affects the success rate and how many additional runs retries will incur. The dice game is an analogy.

Comment: @JasonBaker Ah, that makes sense.